# Why do I have to wait for iframes to be ready after setting variables?

Tags: html, vba, excel, iframe

over the past weeks I struggled, but with the help of Google, managed to solve a fair amount of problems. Now, after finishing the code, I want to remove obsolete lines for better readability and stumbled onto a problem I don't understand.
It might be because I am just mediocre in VBA programming and not at all versed in HTML, please excuse this if the answer is easy and obvious.
I want to understand the problem for future coding, so I understand why it has to be done this way.

For security reasons I cannot post the HTML code of the intranet site I am navigating.
The portion of the code I don't understand is this:

```
Dim IE As New InternetExplorerMedium
Dim Doc As IHTMLDocument
Dim FrmDoc As Object
Dim iFrm as HTMLIFrame
Set Doc = IE.Document
[navigating to the intranet site]

    Set iFrm = Doc.getElementById("ivuFrm_page0ivu2")
    Set FrmDoc = iFrm.contentWindow.Document
    Do While FrmDoc.ReadyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop
    Set iFrm = FrmDoc.getElementById("isolatedWorkArea")
    Do While iFrm.ReadyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop

[downloading the report]
```

If I remove either of those Loops I get an "Object- or With-blockvariable not set" error when using either variable. So those don't exist when I'm not waiting.

If I set the iFrm variable like this:

```
iFrm = Doc.getElementById("ivuFrm_page0ivu2").contentWindow.Document.getElementById("isolatedWorkArea")
```

I get an "Access restricted" error when using the variable.

Why is that?

Comment: Maybe this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534622(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RyanWildry Would I find the attribute in the DOM Explorer when searching for "security" if it was set?

Comment: If you want to know why you are getting that error, this is one possible cause. Look at the HTML to know for sure.

Comment: @RyanWildry Apologies for being vague. I looked at the HTML but couldn't find anything regarding security.
I just now realized that I asked to different questions regarding iframes. I suppose that only shows how little I know about iframes